# SQL Process left behind?

Tags: java, sql, tomcat, process

I got a Java app as front end and MS SQL server as back end. DBA stated that when end user closed the Java app or the web browser, the SQL statement that initiated was still running at the database. Is that possible? Or it should automatically terminated by the Tomcat server already? How to verify and anyway to ensure killing the pending process when end user does exit or left the app?

Java version: 8
Tomcat: 8
SQL server: 2012.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that possible?

Yes.

> Or it should automatically terminated by the Tomcat server already?

If the Tomcat server ... or more likely the application ... doesn't explicitly close the JDBC connection or call `cancel()` on the running statement, then it will keep running.

> How to verify and anyway to ensure killing the pending process when end user does exit or left the app?

When you detect that the user has "gone away", explicitly close the JDBC connection or cancel and close the statement if you are using a connection pool and the connection can be recycled.

Comment: Can Tomcat have such configuration to explicitly close the JDBC once the user turn off the session? I will check the application on such call. Thanks.

Comment: The problem is that Tomcat may not know what connections your webapp has opened.  And it won't know which connections are associated with a specific user session.  You need to do any end-of-session disconnection explicitly in your webapp.